# How do I set the Sitecore 8 default login redirect /start page?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

Maybe I've just run out of my Google mojo, but I can't figure this out:

In Sitecore 8 user settings, I can set a "Start URL" per user - in other words the page/url, which the user gets directed to after login success. The interface for setting this value looks like this:

[image]

If I click off *Desktop* and hit save, the value of the *StartUrl* field is set to `/sitecore/shell/default.aspx` and the user gets redirected to the classic "Lighthouse" desktop.

If I click off *Content Editor* and hit save, the value of the *StartUrl* field is set to `/sitecore/shell/applications/clientusesoswindows.aspx` and the user gets redirected to the content editor, effectively `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content editor.aspx` (an extra redirect occurs).

If I click off *Default* and hit save, the value of the *StartUrl* field is set to the empty string, and the user gets redirected to the Launchpad thing, effectively `/sitecore/shell/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad.aspx`.

**My question is:** How do I change the default behaviour, i.e. how do I decide where the user is redirected to, if he or she chooses *Default*? I want them to go to the Content Editor per default, they don't really fancy the Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

When you select *default* in the user manager, it effectively sets the user profile *StartUrl* value to empty. That just directs the user to `/sitecore` on your site after they login.

`/sitecore` has a 302 redirect to the launch pad. I haven't worked out where that is set yet.

An option would be to customize the `loggingin` pipeline. The default setup for that is:

```xml
<loggingin argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.LoggingInArgs">
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.ClearCache, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.CheckClientUser, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.CheckStartUrl, Sitecore.Kernel" />
</loggingin>
```

You could add a new processor in instead the `CheckStartUrl` processor and if the *StartUrl* is empty, update it to your default from a setting etc...

Something like this*:

```cs
public class CustomCheckStartUrl : CheckStartUrl
{
    protected override bool ValidateStartUrl(LoggingInArgs args)
    {
        var isValid = base.ValidateStartUrl(args);

        // override the default start url
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.StartUrl))
        {
            args.StartUrl = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("MyDefaultStartPage", string.Empty);
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

And patch that into the pipeline.

**untested code*